# How to disable creating .pf (prefetch) file in Windows MFC application?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, prefetch

I'm writing a C++ MFC application. I want to avoid writing any data on HDD during program execution.

When I open up my application, Windows immediately creates a `.pf` file in a directory `..\Windows\Prefetch\`.

I cannot disable registry value responsible for prefetching (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters\EnablePrefetcher`), because my application has to run on many different machines, and some of users may don't even know how to run regedit.

Could you tell me if there is any option to disable creating this file in my application?

Comment: Is that really generated by the application or just by the OS? If it's the OS then there's probably nothing you can do about it, nor is it really going to cause you any problems (unless you're trying to hide that you've run that process on that machine?)

Comment: yes, this file is creating by the OS, not by my application. I'm writing data recovery program, so I don't want to make any changes on HDD (eg. run application from pen drive).

Comment: Are you linking with /SWAPRUN ?

Comment: @Stefan I've just tried every combination of running with /SWAPRUN (CD/NET), and it didn't gave me any change. btw. why do you think, this may help?

Comment: How about writing to the registry in the start up of the application.

Comment: The .pf file is small potatoes, the paging file is much bigger.  Real data recovery programs boot their own OS.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the SuperFetch service as described [here](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/c906e110-6b30-495a-ad62-b5990b13a66c.aspx). I would try this in `InitInstance`. If that proves to be too late, I would stop the service before the software is run.